# How do I send a byteArrayOutputStream via soap from C# to a Java WebService?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I'm used to sending files via SOAP to / from C# based web services and we've always used the "byte[]" type for the contents of the file.

However, I've now got a java web service that wants a byteArrayOutputStream and I have no idea how to send it one from my C# client.

The WSDL shows it as

```
<xs:element name="baos" type="tns:byteArrayOutputStream" minOccurs="0" />
```

adding the web reference to the project generates the following empty (aside from the INotify... stuff) classes

```
    public partial class byteArrayOutputStream : outputStream {
    }

    public abstract partial class outputStream : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
       // boring INotifyPropertyChanged stuff removed
    }
```

This seems completely worthless / unusable, so I either need to:

- figure out how to add the web reference differently

or

- figure out how to use this generated class.

As a last resort I will ask the java team to just accept a byte[] instead of a ByteArrayOutputStream, *but, does anyone have any idea how I can currently consume this java based web service to send files to it from my C# client?*

Comment: Why is accepting a byte[] a last resort? I've found that using simple types where possible is better for interop in web services.

Comment: Well, I guess I just didn't want to ask someone to change code because I couldn't figure it out.  I agree though, byte[] is ideal in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is an Axis web service you're trying to call. Some older versions of Axis fail to define certain types in the `apachesoap` namespace. They may simply need to upgrade their Axis version.

Alternatively, I'd tell them what I tell .NET Web Service creators: do not return platform-specific types from a web service. Web Services are meant to be interoperable - what's the sense in returning a byteOutputStream or a Map or a DataSet to a platform which knows nothing about that type?

Comment: I thought the whole point of soap was to avoid platform specific stuff like this.  We ended up resolving this by having him change it to byte[].

Comment: It is. But some platforms (at one time) didn't test with others. I think this is fixed in later versions of Axis. I've actually seen Axis schemas that have a definition for apacheSoap:Map, for instance.